# How do I fix my anchor tags in my navigation?

Tags: html, css, web, anchor

I'm creating my portfolio website and I'm having some issues with any anchor tag within my navigation. When I hover over the link, it appears correctly, but nothing happens when I click on it. Both html pages are in the same folder (although I'm not getting a typical page not found error anyway). Here is an example of a link the the homepage through the logo:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="padding-top:2px;">
   <img src="logo.svg" alt="" width="190px" style="padding:0px"/>
</a>
```

Here is another example within the menu, where I'm linking to the use-cases section of in the homepage:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html#usecases">CASE STUDIES</a></li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE:
The issue was being caused by an event listener that changes the default behavior of the code. In this case I was using the following event listener:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You have a click event listener that prevents the default behavior when the user clicks on the link.

Comment: @Spectric Thank you so much. I'm not sure how I overlooked that, but I removed the event listener and it works great.